# How to read a .edg file for network data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I am tryin to read file named as les_miserables_edge_file.edg and the file looks like this:

source  target  value
Myriel  Napoleon    1
Myriel  MlleBaptistine  8
Myriel  MmeMagloire 10
Myriel  CountessDeLo    1
Myriel  Geborand    1
Myriel  Champtercier    1
Myriel  Cravatte    1
Myriel  Count   2
Myriel  OldMan  1
Myriel  Valjean 5

I am trying this:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
G=nx.read_edgelist("les_miserables_edge_file.edg", nodetype=int)
G=nx.read_edgelist("les_miserables_edge_file.edg",create_using=nx.DiGraph())
```

But it gies me an error that I dont understand:

---Unexpected exception formatting exception. Falling back to standard exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\edgelist.py", line 257, in parse_edgelist
u = nodetype(u)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'source'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3369, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6696\450509644.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
G=nx.read_edgelist("les_miserables_edge_file.edg", nodetype=int)
File "<class 'networkx.utils.decorators.argmap'> compilation 5", line 5, in argmap_read_edgelist_1
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\edgelist.py", line 376, in read_edgelist
return parse_edgelist(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\edgelist.py", line 260, in parse_edgelist
raise TypeError(
TypeError: Failed to convert nodes source,target to type <class 'int'>.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1982, in showtraceback
stb = self.InteractiveTB.structured_traceback(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1118, in structured_traceback
return FormattedTB.structured_traceback(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1012, in structured_traceback
return VerboseTB.structured_traceback(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 865, in structured_traceback
formatted_exception = self.format_exception_as_a_whole(etype, evalue, etb, number_of_lines_of_context,
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 818, in format_exception_as_a_whole
frames.append(self.format_record(r))
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 736, in format_record
result += ''.join(_format_traceback_lines(frame_info.lines, Colors, self.has_colors, lvals))
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
value = obj.**dict**[self.func.**name**] = self.func(obj)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\core.py", line 698, in lines
pieces = self.included_pieces
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
value = obj.**dict**[self.func.**name**] = self.func(obj)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\core.py", line 649, in included_pieces
pos = scope_pieces.index(self.executing_piece)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\utils.py", line 145, in cached_property_wrapper
value = obj.**dict**[self.func.**name**] = self.func(obj)
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\stack_data\core.py", line 628, in executing_piece
return only(
File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\executing\executing.py", line 164, in only
raise NotOneValueFound('Expected one value, found 0')
executing.executing.NotOneValueFound: Expected one value, found 0.

any idea why this error is rising?

P.s: I was following networkx documentation!
​
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help:

```
Data = open('les_miserables_edge_file.edg', "r")
next(Data, None)  # skip the first line in the input file
Graphtype = nx.Graph()

G = nx.parse_edgelist(Data, delimiter=' ', create_using=Graphtype,
                      nodetype=str, data=(('weight', int),))
```